# How to merge two tables sql on id?

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have two tables `df1` and `df2`

**df1**

```
ID   val1 val2 val3
1     5    6    7
1     2    8    7
1     3    0    1
2     5    6    7
2     3    0    1
3     3    0    4
3     7    7    4
3     9    2    4
3     0    0    4
```

**df2**

```
ID
1
2
```

I would like to merge on `ID` and get only the values of the IDs in `df2`:

```
ID   val1 val2 val3
1     5    6    7
1     2    8    7
1     3    0    1
2     5    6    7
2     3    0    1
```

Comment: use join : `df1.join(df2, ["ID"], "inner")`

Comment: Hi @emax, as a member, for almost 6 year now, you should be aware of the meaning of feedback. A comment, a vote up for a good help or acceptance of the answers are all good tools for feedback from the one who asked a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT df1.* 
FROM df1
RIGHT JOIN df2
ON df1.ID = df2.ID
```

or

```
SELECT df1.* 
FROM DF2
LEFT JOIN DF1
ON df1.ID = df2.ID;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=676c62c8e3d3a927a2229a8607cd805c) how this worls on SQL Server.

Comment: INNER JOIN, OP wants only the ID's found in df2.

Comment: Hi @emax , hope one of this options helped you? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `JOIN`:

```
select df1.*
from df1 join
     df2
     on df1.id = df2.id;
```

You can also do this with `IN` or `EXISTS` in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from df1
where id in (select id from df2);
```

This might be what you are looking for? This way the df2 table column id works as a filter.